# Failed deploy on OpenShift

Tags: build, jenkins, openshift

I cannot deploy on openshift. I have a Jboss server, mongodb and jenkins as cartridges. The application is not scalable. The build is succesful.
Here are the last console lines:

```
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is f62b813b
Activating deployment
Starting MongoDB cartridge
Deploying JBoss
Starting jbossas cartridge
Found 127.10.192.1:8080 listening port
Found 127.10.192.1:9999 listening port
/var/lib/openshift/538c7f614382ec6016000002/jbossas/standalone/deployments /var/lib/openshift/538c7f614382ec6016000002/jbossas
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
/var/lib/openshift/538c7f614382ec6016000002/jbossas
Failed deployments: ./ROOT.war
Archiving artifacts
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe your war file is taking to long to deploy.  How long does it take to spin up that application locally?  You should try building the war file locally and then using SCP to transfer it to your gear and deploy it and see if that works.

Comment: done, i found figured it out from the logs. it was wrong database host

Comment: @corey112358 Could you please elaborate. I am having the same problem and am not familiar with SCP